# Ant outofdate check on files in the same directory anywhere in a path

Tags: django, ant, mapping, translation

I'm trying to setup an Ant task to check if django message files (.po) have been updated since the .mo files were last generated.

This appeared to be a fairly simple task after I'd put the following together;

```
<!-- Check if messages need to be compiled -->
<target name="init.trans.update.check" depends="init.properties">
    <outofdate property="trans.required" outputsourcespath="whatsnew_path" verbose="true">
        <sourcefiles>
            <fileset dir="src">
                <include name="**/*.po"/>
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
        <targetfiles>
            <fileset dir="src">
                <include name="**/*.mo"/>
            </fileset>
        </targetfiles>
        <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.*)\.po$$" to="\1.mo"/>
        <sequential>
            <echo>The messages do need recompiling, the following files have changed:</echo>
            <property refid="whatsnew_path" name="whatsnew"/>
            <echo>${whatsnew}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </outofdate>
</target>
```

However with the `verbose` option enabled it is showing me that it's comparing files in different paths, so it says `\src\mysite\locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\django.po outofdate with regard to \src\debug_toolbar\locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\django.mo`.

Is there something that can be done with this implementation to ensure the path to each file is the same when the comparison is made? I don't want to have to explicitly list all the paths.

Comment: Can you specifically list the folders rather than just 'src'?  Guessing the "**" on the include is what is biting you since it matches all - maybe there's an option on the include or a different way of specifying that.   You could also consider writing your own Ant task that works off a list of src folders, then you can build the target path based on what you know.

Comment: @mikemil yeah that's the option I hoped to avoid. I hoped ant might have something to make it easier than maintaining a list of hard coded dirs. Maybe I can write a macro to match a file type and use that to get the paths to compare.